# VE not stopable

Tags: debian, openvz

One of my VEs sometimes stops working.
I cannot reach it via HTTP, FTP or SSH, I only can enter it per vzctl enter X

All tries to restart the VE result in a 'Operation timed out', even if I try 'vzctl stop X --fast'.
I cannot restart /etc/init.d/vz because this operation also wants to stop the VE and runs into a timeout. Same problem if I try to reboot the server.
So each times this happens I have to do a hardware reset of the host node to get my VE up and running again.

Where is the best point to start searching for the problem?

Comment: /proc/user_beancounters

Comment: There haven't been any faults for the dead machine

Comment: That happens to me when NFS mounted inside the container freezes and cannot be unmounted.

Comment: Post your uname -r please.